# ASP.NET C# + Nhibernate HTTP module (Session per request) - restrict request types

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I have implemented the [Session per request](http://code.google.com/p/walkme/source/browse/trunk/NerdDinner.Data/NHibernateSessionPerRequest+.cs?r=8) pattern for managing nhibernate sessions.

Because it is an httpmodule it runs for every request, be it a jpg or png. Is there a way to only get the module to create a session if the request is made through the MVC framework? I.E excluding png/jpg etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathieu is right, however it is a good practice for ASP.NET MVC projects to open sessions in an ActionFilter class.You can register it in GlobalFilterCollection, if you want it to run for every action. Take a look at this [blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4809/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-what-about-transactions) (also from Ayende, but MVC specific).

Comment: +1 This is most definetely the best approach, It used to grate me that I was opening/closing sessions 20+ times during a page request when using http modules. However you may also need to catch unhandled exceptions and rollback as well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with that, creating a new session is just newing a few objects. Full explanation here from Ayende : http://ayende.com/blog/4123/what-is-the-cost-of-opening-a-session